# Output of bash loop iteration into next iteration

Tags: bash

I have a list of substitutions that I would like to perform with `sed`. Instead of combining the substitutions into a single `sed` command, I would like to perform each substitution in an iteration of a bash loop. For example:

```
cat ${input} |
for subst in "${substlist}"; do
    sed 's/'${subst}'/modified_'${subst}'/g'
done > ${output}
```

I would expect that each iteration modifies the entire stream but I'm only seeing that the first iteration gets the input.

Is this pattern possible in bash?

Comment: BTW, `${substlist}` is expanding a string -- generally speaking, you should use a proper array rather than relying on word-splitting via unquoted expansion. That is, the best practice is `substlist=( "first" "second" "third" ); for subst in "${substlist[@]}"; do ...`

Comment: Why don't you want to combine them into a single `sed` command? That's what several of the answers do.

Comment: BTW, if you want to run all the substitutions at once (that is, concurrently) in different `sed` processes (for whatever odd reason), the kind of "looping" most applicable for that is a recursive function, vs a bash `for` loop. For example: `multised() { case $# in 0) cat;; 1) sed -e "$1";; *) local cur=$1; shift; sed -e "$cur" | multised "$@";; esac; }` -- usable as `multised "${substs[@]}" <"$input" >"$output"` if you have your `substs` in an array.

Comment: This was more of an exploratory question since bash didn't really work the way I expected in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Create an array of `-e` options to pass to `sed`.

```
filters=()
for subst in ${substlist}; do
    filters+=(-e "s/$subst/modified_$subst/")
done
sed "${filters[@]}" "$input" > "$output"
```

(The question of iterating over an unquoted parameter expansion and dynamically creating each `sed` filter is beyond the scope of this answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it as a single stream. Building up the sed arguments from `${substlist}` and calling sed once:

```
#!/bin/sh 

cat ${input} |
sed `for subst in ${substlist}; do
        echo " -e s/${subst}/modified_${subst}/g "
     done` > ${output}
```

Depending on what is in `${substlist}` you may need to do additional escaping.

Comment: It's bad enough that the OP is already running unquoted expansion once. Doing unquoted expansion *of the output from that* is adding more failure cases for no purpose. (Also, on account of bash's `echo` being noncompliant with the POSIX spec, the `-e` here modifies how it behaves rather than causing `sed` to be passed a literal `-e` argument, the net result of which is that all but one of the substitutions will be treated as an input filename, and not an operation to perform, by `sed`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Edited to indicate #!/bin/sh but agree the portability issues with echo make it a poor solution.

Comment: You might switch to `printf` instead. Even if bash is running in POSIX mode (started under the `/bin/sh` name), it only has a compliant `echo` if the `xpg_echo` option is also enabled (whether at compile-time or runtime). Could also `echo " -e s/${subst}/modified_${subst}/g "` to the same effect, I suppose.

Comment: Applied that myself; hope I didn't overstep. Should probably also add quotes around the variables expanded for filenames `> "$output"`, `cat "$input"` -- or replacing that one with a `<"$input"` on the `sed -- but I'd rather avoid being heavy-handed where possible.

Answer (score -1):

Copy the input file to the output file, then perform the `sed` substitutions using the `-i` option to keep overwriting that file.

```
cp "$input" "$output"
for subst in $substlist
do
    sed -i "s/$subst/modified_$subst/g" "$output"
done
```

With BSD/OSX `sed` that needs to be:

```
sed -i '' "s/$subst/modified_$subst/g" "$output"
```

Comment: Extra copy operations, and takes a portability hit (won't work with BSD `sed`'s version of `-i`), to what end?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy They said they didn't want to do it in a single `sed` command.

Comment: Ahh. I'd be... interested... to know if there's a real reason for that (vs being an XY problem -- ie. not knowing that a loop could be used to build an argument list), but fair 'nuff.

Comment: Me, too. I just asked in a comment.

Comment: Perhaps I have a good use-case? I'm running into a similar problem with grep, though I think I better explain the reason I need it to be separate commands for each iteration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52999792/output-of-previous-bash-loop-iteration-into-next-iteration-for-varying-grep-comm

I can't seem to find anywhere where this is addressed. Perhaps a sign that it's just not the right way to go about things. :(