# Output of previous bash loop iteration into next iteration for varying grep commands

Tags: bash, grep

I'm in a situation where I'm wanting to take the output of a grep command from one iteration of a for-loop and turn it into the input for the next grep command in the following iteration.

Normally, I would use an array and the for-loop to build a single grep command, however because I need the bash variable `GREP_COLOR` to change between iterations I'm running into this issue. I suppose I could make three different functions that all do the same thing except for that variable, but I'd prefer to have a single function if at all possible. Here's the array:

```
patterns=("general-red" "general-yellow" "general-green" "ha-red" "ha-yellow" "ha-green")
```

Here's the function:

```
function iterate-patterns() {
    for i in "${patterns[@]}"
    do
            if [[ "$i" = *-red ]]
            then
                    GREP_COLOR="$RED" grep -E --text --color=always --line-buffered -f /var/lib/foobar/"${i}".txt
            elif [[ "$i" = *-yellow ]]
            then
                    GREP_COLOR="$YELLOW" grep -E --text --color=always --line-buffered -f /var/lib/foobar/"${i}".txt
            elif [[ "$i" = *-green ]]
            then
                    GREP_COLOR="$GREEN" grep -E --text --color=always --line-buffered -f /var/lib/foobar/"${i}".txt 
            else
                    cat 
            fi
    done
}
```

Here's the function that calls that function, providing the initial input:

```
function daddyfunction() {

    iterate-filters |\
    iterate-experimental |\
    iterate-patterns 
}
```

Essentially, each item in the array represents a file for the `grep -f` command with many patterns to be searched for and highlighted with the desired color. However, as the code currently stands, only the first array item ends up being displayed. This I'm fairly certain is because each grep needs to be somehow changed into input for the following iteration's grep command.

Is this do-able? Am I stuck making a function for each color? Is there a better way to accomplish all this? I seek the wisdom of the internets. ;) Please and thank you.

#### EDIT

Just to confirm, three separate functions does work:

```
function iterate-redhighlights() {
    greplist=()
    for i in "${redpatterns[@]}"
    do
            if [[ "$i" = *-red ]]
            then
                    greplist+=( -f /var/lib/foobar/"${i}".txt)
            else
                    cat
            fi
    done
    GREP_COLOR="$RED" $search "${greplist[@]}"
}
function iterate-yellowhighlights() {
    greplist=()
    for i in "${yellowpatterns[@]}"
    do
            if [[ "$i" = *-yellow ]]
            then
                    greplist+=( -f /var/lib/foobar/"${i}".txt)
            else
                    cat
            fi
    done
    GREP_COLOR="$YELLOW" $search "${greplist[@]}"
}
function iterate-greenhighlights() {
    greplist=()
    for i in "${greenpatterns[@]}"
    do
            if [[ "$i" = *-green ]]
            then
                    greplist+=( -f /var/lib/foobar/"${i}".txt)
            else
                    cat
            fi
    done
    GREP_COLOR="$GREEN" $search "${greplist[@]}"
}
```

Comment: The first iteration of the loop will read all of `stdin`. When the loop repeats, there's nothing left to read, so `grep` will exit immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run `grep` in a loop when it's reading from `stdin`. The first iteration will read all of `stdin`, and there's no way to rewind back to the beginning for the next iteration (files support seeking, but pipes don't, and there's no shell syntax to do it).

You can copy all of `stdin` to a temporary file before the loop and then process that file each time. Redirect the output to another temporary file, then copy that back over the input file to prepare for the next iteration.

```
iterate-patterns() {
    tempfile=$(mktemp /tmp/patterns.XXXXXX)
    tempfile2=$(mktemp /tmp/patterns2.XXXXXX)
    cat > "$tempfile"
    for i in "${patterns[@]}"
    do
        if [[ "$i" = *-red ]]
        then
            GREP_COLOR="$RED" grep -E --text --color=always --line-buffered -f /var/lib/foobar/"${i}".txt "$tempfile" > "$tempfile2"
        elif [[ "$i" = *-yellow ]]
        then
            GREP_COLOR="$YELLOW" grep -E --text --color=always --line-buffered -f /var/lib/foobar/"${i}".txt "$tempfile" > "$tempfile2"
        elif [[ "$i" = *-green ]]
        then
            GREP_COLOR="$GREEN" grep -E --text --color=always --line-buffered -f /var/lib/foobar/"${i}".txt "$tempfile" > "$tempfile2"
        else
            cat "$tempfile" > "$tempfile2"
        fi
        cp "$tempfile2" "$tempfile"
    done
    cat "$tempfile"
    rm "$tempfile" "$tempfile2"
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid that was the answer. I was curious whether there'd be some magical way to convert it back to input before the next iteration, but I think you're right. Going along with that a `|` does not work mid-loop probably emphasizing that same problem.

Comment: Turning the output into input wouldn't even help in this case. If a line is not matched by the first pattern, it won't be included in the output, so then you won't see it if it's matched by the second pattern.

Comment: When you have a sequence of `grep` in a price you get the intersection of all the matches, but you want the union.

Comment: The way I have my greps setup it doesn't remove non-matched lines, it just doesn't highlight them.

Comment: How are you doing that?

Comment: Each of the patterns I use ends with `|$`. So if I create a file.txt with the word "green" but want it to show other lines as well I do: "GREP_COLOR='01;32' grep -E --color=always "green|$" file.txt"

Comment: OK, then you need to redirect the `grep` output back to the input file. But since you can't use the same file for input and output, you'll need two temp files.

Comment: It would be more efficient if you could combine all the pattern files for the same color, so you didn't need to process the file separately for each of them.